# Spatial autocorrelation weight matrix for heatmaps

Tags: autocorrelation, spatial, similarities, weights, heatmap

I am not an advanced mathematician and I'm very new to spatial autocorrelation. So I apologize if my question seems primitive in any way.

I'm looking for ways to quantify the distribution similarity of two heatmaps. The heatmaps are saliency maps generated from an AI model (see below for an example of a corresponding pair of heatmaps).

One way I thought might be promising to achieve a similarity score is by performing global spatial autocorrelation techniques like Moran's I on the difference of the two heatmaps. I understand that I would need a weight matrix for that to work (found some methods from PySAL [here](https://pysal.org/libpysal/api.html)), but I'm honestly clueless as to which method is most appropriate for an application like this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also if you think spatial auto correlation is not the best approach here, please let me know if you can think of something better. Many thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]